# PrimeFaces: Custom validate date in p:inputText with ajax

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

I want to use a custom validator (present or future) on a `<p:inputText type="date">`. It's based on a legacy database. The field is a datetime but the time part doesn't matter and is '00:00:00' in the database in all cases. So 'present' in this case means a datetime of today, even though it really is in today's past.

Currently I have this in my page:

```
<p:column headerText="Prognose" width="160">
    <p:inputText id="fieldMilestoneTarget" value="#{mil.target}" type="date" 
        validator="#{futureOrPresentIgnoreTimeValidator.validate}"
        validatorMessage="Das Prognose-Datum von Meilensteinen darf nicht in der Vergangenheit liegen">
        <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" timeZone="CET" />
        <p:ajax event="change" update=":contentform:tabView:milestoneWarningPanel messageMilestoneTarget" />
    </p:inputText>
    <p:message for="@previous" id="messageMilestoneTarget" />
</p:column>
```

FutureOrPresentIgnoreTimeValidator.java:

```
@Named
@FacesValidator("futureOrPresentIgnoreTimeValidator")
public class FutureOrPresentIgnoreTimeValidator implements Validator<Date> {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Date value)
        throws ValidatorException {
        if (context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{indexController.adminMode}", Boolean.class))
            return;
        if (value == null)
            return;
        Date today = new Date();
        today.setHours(0);
        today.setMinutes(0);
        today.setSeconds(0);
        
        value.setSeconds(1); // Millisekunden führen sonst zu Problemen
        
        if (value.before(today))
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                "Das Datum darf nicht in der Vergangenheit liegen", null));
    }
}
```

When the user uses the helper within the `<p:inputText>` to select a date everything works as expected. But when typing, there are 2 errors/problems:

1. The validator runs on every keystroke. What I want is to validate when the user is 'ready', e.g. focus is lost or something in this direction.
2. While typing the year e.g. for 06.06.2023 (my local format) for the moment the field shows '06.06.0002'. As the validator runs on every keystroke this leads to a `java.lang.ClassCastException: class sun.util.calendar.JulianCalendar$Date cannot be cast to class sun.util.calendar.Gregorian$Date (sun.util.calendar.JulianCalendar$Date and sun.util.calendar.Gregorian$Date are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`. If a user enters this date it should of course still be validated.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about changing your AJAX event to `blur` from `change` ?

Comment: That's a really good idea. I think I was confused by the blur effect and ignored this event. However a year like 0002 still turns into a julian calendar thus an exception. Does anyone know how I can interpret the date as gregorian in any cases?

Comment: So when using blur if you always want Gregorian don't you need a `converter` not a `validator` ?

Comment: A converter would be a moment too late in my opinion. When entering the year 2023 it works as expected - so I think PrimeFaces decides "on it own" which data type it uses to invoke the validator. What I'd rather do is force it by some parameter to treat the year 0002 the same as the year 2023. Is that possible?

Comment: Understood.  Without studying the code I am not sure other option is trying to hack the JS code on the client side to convert 0002 to 2023 etc.  Just plug into the JS widget.